# R Scrape-Loop hangs itself up

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping, apply, rvest

I am working since a while now on the following problem:
I have a vector with +22'000 URL's that I put in a scrape-loop.
The scrape loop doesn't give me any error message but suddenly stops working, even if the code is still running (the red stop sign stays but the loop does not actually run anymore). It seems like R hangs itself up.

My guess is, that is has something to do with open connections, even if I inserted a 'close(url)' code.

```
install.packages("pacman")
require(pacman)

pacman::p_load(stringr, tibble, xml2, stringr, dplyr, tidyr, base, readxl,rvest,RCurl)

OEM_Nummer_Toner<-read_html('https://www.tonerpartner.ch/oem-Nummer/')%>%
  html_nodes('ul>li>a')%>%
  html_attr('href')

Output <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=1, nrow=0))
colnames(Output)<-'URL'

i<-1      

for (j in OEM_Nummer_Toner) {

  Sys.sleep(runif(1, min=0.5, max=1))
  
  url<- paste0('https://www.tonerpartner.ch',j)
  
  if (url.exists(url)==TRUE){
  
  url<-url(url,'rb')
  html<-read_html(url)
  close(url)
  
  update<- html %>%
    html_nodes('.articletitle')%>%
    html_attr('href')
  
  update<-as.tibble(update)
  
  names(update)<-'URL'
  
  Output<<-rbind(Output, update)
  }
  else
    {}
  print(i)
  print(j)
  print(update)
  i<-i+1
}
```

The first loops generates the vector to loop throug in the second loop.

I work on this problem since long but I don't even really find out what the problem is.

Thank you so much!
David

Comment: You can verify your connection number theory, e.g. on a linux system [this way](https://serverfault.com/questions/269289/how-do-i-check-how-many-http-connections-are-open-currently#269293).  I think `if(url.exists(url)==TRUE)` can be reduce to `if(url.exists(url))`. You could just [debug](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio) your code to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You are growing object in a `for` loop which is very inefficient and slow. Try :

```
urls <- paste0('https://www.tonerpartner.ch',OEM_Nummer_Toner)

purrr::map_df(urls, ~{
  Sys.sleep(runif(1, min=0.5, max=1))
  if(RCurl::url.exists(.x)) 
    tibble(URL = .x %>% 
                  read_html %>% 
                  html_nodes('.articletitle') %>% 
                  html_attr('href'))

  else tibble(URL = NA)
}) -> result
```